# Why does the package babel[french] destroy \@for loops?

Tags: babel, loops, french

Why does this minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\begin{document}

\def\names{Toto,Titi,Tete,Tutu}
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=\names\do{\textbf{\next} }
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

lead to this error message:

```
Runaway argument?
\next :=\names \do {\textbf {\next } } \makeatother \par \end {docume\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@for.
```

but the same code works perfectly if I delete the line

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
```

and of course, is there any solution that preserves the use of the [french] option?

Comment: I would add to the answers below that if you use `\@for` at a document level, you're probably doing something wrong.  It should presumably be wrapped inside macros with a better semantic.  Then just define that macro before `\usepackage[francais]{babel}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `french` makes `:` into an active character (after `\begin{document}`.

Solutions.

1. Define your own list processor in the preamble

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \newcommand{\bflist}[1]{\@for\next:=#1\do{\textbf{\next}}}
   \makeatother
   ```

   and use `\bflist{\names}`
2. Force `:` to have the correct category code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[francais]{babel}
   \begin{document}

   \def\names{Toto,Titi,Tete,Tutu}
   \makeatletter
   \expandafter\@for\expandafter\next\string:=\names\do{\textbf{\next} }
   \makeatother

   \end{document}
   ```

The package `etoolbox` defines some list processing macros that shouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 6):

French babel uses active characters. You must disable this before use `:=`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\begin{document}

\def\names{Toto,Titi,Tete,Tutu}
\makeatletter
\shorthandoff{:}
\@for\next:=\names\do{\textbf{\next} }
\shorthandon{:}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own loop, which, unlike LaTeX's `\@for`, is even expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\amfor#1#2{\doam{#2}#1,\doam,}
\def\doam#1#2,{\ifx\doam#2\amend\fi#1{#2}\doam{#1}}
\def\amend#1\doam#2{\fi}

\begin{document}
% The equivalent of Cristo's original example:
\amfor{Toto,Titi,Tete,Tutu}\textbf
\par\bigskip

% More tests:
\def\dspace#1{\def\cspace{\def\cspace{\space#1\space}}}
\dspace\textbullet
\amfor{Toto,Titi,Tete,Tutu}{\cspace\textbf}
\par\bigskip

\dspace{\textcolor{red}\textasteriskcentered}
\def\do#1{\cspace\textbf{#1}}
\amfor{Toto,Titi,Tete,Tutu}\do
\par\bigskip

% Building a stack in an expandable fashion:
\newcount\nr\nr=2\relax
\def\eat#1{}
\def\do#1{%
  \let\noexpand#1%
  \expandafter\noexpand\csname\expandafter\eat\string#1/\romannumeral\nr\endcsname
}
\edef\x{\amfor{\cmda,\cmdb,\cmdc}\do}
\def\strippref#1>{}
{\tt\expandafter\strippref\meaning\x}
\end{document}
```